# Hide column values for some rows in auto-updatable views while retaining the "write" capability for them in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, view

Suppose i have a view defined like this

```
create or replace view clients as
    select 
    id, name, 
    case app_user_type() -- hide column content for everyone except the administrator
        when 'administrator' then address 
        else null 
    end as address
from data.clients
```

The purpose is to hide the contents of the `address` column in some cases (`current_user <> 'administrator'`).

The problem is that the "address" column becomes readonly.
Is there a way to have the same effect (hide the column value) while retaing the updatable property?

Comment: You need an `instead of` trigger.

Comment: I was aware of that option but i wanted specifically to avoid triggers.

Answer (score 2):

I went with something like this

```
create or replace view clients as
    select id, name, address
    from data.clients;
grant select (id, name) on clients to employee;
```

The only downside is that for `employee` role `select *` will fail, but for my use case, specifying the columns is ok